# Name.id encoded in blockchain

Tags: identity

I've been working on a tool to decode hex messages inserted into OP_RETURN.  Whilst looking at strings in the blockchain I keep coming across user names with the format id:name.id.

If you run strings over a blk*.dat file you will find strings such as:

id:muneebmajeed.id

id:andrewlawrence.id

id:nicholas_studholmewilson.id

id:jorisheijne.id

id:algoventures.id

id:bgardineer4.id

I can't figure out what they are?

Comment: Those look like BlockStack IDs. [Reference](https://blockstack.org/blog/browser-public-alpha)

Comment: Thank you for the pointer Eric, I had not come across BlockStack before but it would seem you are right.  Thanks again.

Comment: @EricAllam You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the above comment, these are Blockstack IDs.

https://blockstack.org/blog/browser-public-alpha